# JSP - check form submission

Tags: forms, jsp, form-submit

Let say I have a simple form with no required fields:

```
<form action="index.jsp" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" />
    <input type="text" name="lastName" />
    <input type="text" name="email" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I want to check if the form was submitted by checking the `submit` parameter (because it's always present). In `PHP` I can do a simple

```
if ( $_POST['submit'] )
```

but the `request.getParameter("submit")` doesn't seem to work.

So what's the best way to check if a form was submitted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to give the input element a name. It's the element's name which get sent as request parameter name.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

Then you can check it as follows:

```
if (request.getParameter("submit") != null) {
    // ...
}
```

You perhaps also want to check if `"POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())` is also true.

```
if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod()) && request.getParameter("submit") != null) {
    // ...
}
```

Better, however, would be to use a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) and do the job in `doPost()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way:-

```
if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
    // Form was submitted.
} else {
    // It may be a GET request.
}
```